# Имя конструктора

Tags: java

Вопрос для саморазвития - Есть два класса с разными методами, которые "вызывают" с третьего класса массив слов из интернет страницы на проверку по методам.

Вопрос, почему в одном классе этот метод не вызывает предупреждение -

```
public Analyze(String string) throws IOException {
        arr = new DPage(string).getWords();
    }
```

а в другом пишет, что этот метод имеет имя конструктора и знак предупреждения. Почему так?

Comment: О-о-о, я знаю эту игру! Нам нужно угадать, чем отличаются два класса, не глядя на тот из них, для которого компилятор выдает предупреждение? (А для другого показан какой-то огрызок кода.) Подождите, может быть кто-то захочет с Вами поиграть.

Comment: @Igor они полностью одинаковы, кроме метода поиска(в одном линейный, во втором бинарный), иначе бы не спрашивал

Comment: Если бы они были одинаковы, они бы и компилировались одинаково. Не хотите - как хотите.

Comment: @Igor, ))))))))

Comment: @Igor Вон Qwertiy даже код не нужен.. шарит)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что один из классов называется `Analize`, а между `public` и `Analize` стоит `void`.